# django global object individual user relation

Tags: django

I have two main models, Comic and Issue, A single comic has multiple issues. I am trying to figure out how to get issues that a specific user has read. I was thinking of creating another model called ReadIssue to store the read state but can't figure out how to get a read property on each issue depending on the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood in your text, this could be a way to build the basic models

```
class Comic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Issue(models.Model):
    comic = models.ForeignKey(Comic, related_name='issues')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def was_read_by(self, user):
        return bool(self.users.filter(user=user).count())

class ReadIssue(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='read')
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue, related_name='users')
```

Now you can do queries like this

```
user = Users.objects.get(pk=1)
comic = Comic.objects.get(pk=1)

first_issue = comic.issues.all().first()

user_read_it = first_issue.was_read_by(user)
```

So you just check if the combination `user-issue` exists in the `ReadIssue` table. Of course it  would be a good idea to add an `index_together` for that pair, because that's how you will most likely do all look-ups in that table.

And by adding these little helper methods to the models, you can make the whole thing very expressive and easy to follow.

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for. To use this in a template, I would make a template tag with it correct?

Comment: Yes. And some things you can use directly, like `{% for issue in comic.issues.all %} to loop through all issues of a `comic`.